# reaching the maximum values of equal indexes of arrays existing in the list

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a list , named li, in my project which contains some two dimensional arrays of integer. I want to have the maximum values of equal indexes of arrays and make a new array ,named array2. I have written this code but it's slow.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)//the size of each array is [100,100]
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
    {
        int ma = -2;
        int d = 0;
        while (d <= f)//"f" is the number of items in the list
        {
            ma = Math.Max(ma, Convert.ToInt32(li[d].GetValue(i, j)));
            d++;
        }

        array2[i, j] =  ma;

    }
```

How can I have a better one?
Is it possible to improve by using emguCv? if yes, how can I do that?
thanks in advance.

Comment: It's hard to understand your question at the moment. A short but *complete* example would help, as would making your question body and title each stand alone, as would formatting the code more carefully. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: I'll say that a piece is missing. You start with `named li,`

Answer (score 1):

If `li` is an array of integers, you can change your code to:

```
ma = Math.Max(ma, li[d][i, j]);
```

So you won't have a boxing/unboxing to access the `li` elements (`GetValue` is a slow way to access elements of an array)

To make it more clear:

```
int[,] temp = li[d];
ma = Math.Max(ma, temp[i, j]);
```

Comment: your code didnt work, instead I used this one:int[,] temp = new int[picP.Height, picP.Width];
                       Array.Copy(li[d], temp, li[d].Length);
                       ma = Math.Max(ma, temp[i, j]);and It's very slow

Comment: @AsmaGood What is the type of `li[d]`? You haven't wrote how `li` is defined.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can change the time complexity of your code. At the moment the complexity of your code is `O(n²·f)` which is the best you can hope for, since you have to access at least `n²·f` elements to create `array2` (where `n²` is the size of the two-dimensional array).

You could change the order in which you iterate, but it doesn't change the complexity. It could be a little more cache friendly, depending on the implementation of `GetValue`:

```
for(int d=0; d<f; d++)
{
    var arr = li[d];

    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<100; j++)
        {
            array2[i,j] = Math.Max(array2[i,j], Convert.ToInt32(arr.GetValue(i,j)));
        }
    }
}
```

You should initialize each value of `array2` to `-2` before running this code to make it compatible with your current code.

You might want to try to parallelize you code and use multiple worker threads that calculate different parts of `array2`. If you are using the 4.0 framework than you could use the [Parallel class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.aspx).

Comment: Yeah, it was worth a try, but like I said, there is no way to improve the time complexity. So it's either low-level optimization or parallelization. Low level optimization isn't as easy in C# as it is in C or C++.